# Android: how to start the app intalled in the phone using the packagename and pass it a parameter?

Tags: android, android-activity

**I HAVE REEDITED THE QUESTION**

I am getting the apps installed in the Android phone with the code below. I put the info of the app in an instance of PInfo (one of my customized class).

Now I want to get one of them and open it passing a parameter, I have tried the following:

```
Uri uri =Uri.parse("THEURL");
Intent intent = getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage(((PInfo)apps.get(0)).apppackage);
intent.setData(uri);

startActivity(intent);
```

This opens the app but **how to pass the parameter?** (The code above is not working) For example, a string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Step #1: Get the email address of the developer of the application in question.

Step #2: Ask the developer if they support such a string extra (or data `Uri`, or whatever). If so, follow what they tell you to do. If not, do not attempt to open their app this way.

Step #3: Repeat Steps #1 and #2 for every app you are interested in.

Answer (score 0):

You should create a method that handles the incoming intent and call it within your `onCreate` or `onResume` methods.

You'll pass the information like this:

`intent.putExtra("foo", someString);`

Then you'll try read the information passed along within the intent.

`String incomingString = getIntent().getStringExtra("foo");` should do the trick within your `handleIncomingIntent()`